# How to override a checked out document - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document

I know you can over ride a checked out document on SharePoint - but can you do this on SharePoint online? Im guessing the only factor to consider is weather or not who ever has the document checked out has actually made any changes to it?

If they have and they have a local copy - can they then copy over the top of the checked in document?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are a site admin/ sca you should be able to override the checkout. Select the item/file drop down and click Override checkout. Usually if a file is locked by a user, the lock is release after 5 to 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, and to confirm this will lose any edits by the check out user?